# How can I detect if AVIF image is animated?

Tags: javascript, avif

Is there a way to detect if an AVIF image is animated using plain JavaScript only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [`ImageDecoder` API](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#image-decoding) can tell this to you.

You'd pass a `ReadableStream` of your data to it, and then check if one of the decoder's [`tracks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageTrack) has its `animated` metadata set to true:

```js
if (!window.ImageDecoder) {
  console.warn("Your browser doesn't support the ImageDecoder API yet, we'd need to load a library");
}
// from https://colinbendell.github.io/webperf/animated-gif-decode/avif.html
fetch("https://colinbendell.github.io/webperf/animated-gif-decode/6.avif").then((resp) => test("animated", resp.body));
// from https://github.com/link-u/avif-sample-images cc-by-sa 4.0 Kaede Fujisaki
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/link-u/avif-sample-images/master/fox.profile1.8bpc.yuv444.avif").then((resp) => test("static", resp.body));

document.querySelector("input").onchange = ({target}) => test("your image", target.files[0].stream());


async function test(name, stream) {
  const decoder = new ImageDecoder({ data: stream, type: "image/avif" });
  // wait for we have some metadata
  await decoder.tracks.ready;
  // log if one of the tracks is animated
  console.log(name, [...decoder.tracks].some((track) => track.animated));
}
```

```html
<input type=file>
```

However beware this API is still not widely supported, since [only Chromium based browsers have an implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageDecoder#browser_compatibility) currently.

Comment: I tested this in Chrome and it seems to work. However I'm going to need a polyfill as I specifically need this for Safari 16. Suggestions on a polyfill please?

Comment: Not really no. There is https://github.com/YuriTu/avic.js that apparently can decode it, so it shouldn't be too hard to fork it so that it only outputs the info, but I'm not sure either.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a several hour long project so I'll have to sift through that tomorrow night. If it supports Chrome 57 I think there is a fair chance it should work in Safari 16. I'll let you know how it works out, thank you!

Comment: So I've decided to abandon detecting Safari 16.1 the proper way because there is no *sane* proper way, they screwed up on the release. I'll accept the answer because it's valid in it's own right even though it doesn't help in the context that I needed it for. Thank you nonetheless. 

Comment: Note that the current Technology Preview does support animated avif. Also, it seems that an error event is fired on the HTMLImageElement in currwnt stable when it tries to load such a file.

Comment: I'd be willing to award a full 500 point bounty for a completely self-contained script that would `return true` when detecting animated AVIF in Safari 16.1 and `return false` in Safari 16.0. If you're willing to answer it in that context I'll go make the question and post the URL in my next comment. Are you are interested?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this (seems to be) criminally easy with JavaScript.

Written in TypeScript for posterity:

```js
/**
 * Sniff for an animated AVIF byte
 * @param buffer 
 * @returns boolean
 * @example
 * `return sniffAVIF(
 *   new Uint8Array(
 *     await uploadedFile.arrayBuffer()
 *   )
 * )`
 */
const sniffAVIF = (view: Uint8Array) =>
  return view[ 3 ] === 44;
```

Yes, really!

The first few bytes of every AVIF file (that I have tested at least) tend to look pretty much the same when loaded as a Uint8Array;

`0, 0, 0, 44, 102, 116` for animated files

`0, 0, 0, 28, 102, 116` for static files

So fairly trivial to discern one from the other. Of course, I have only been able to test this on a limited number of images, so please do feel free to correct me if you can find an AVIF that doesn't start with this series of bytes.

Hope this helps!